# How can I get sum of array depends on key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, reduce

I have `object` as following format :

```
let objs = [
    {Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1'}
    {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3'}
    {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6'}
    ]
```

I want to achive an object as following :

```
{Name : 'Total', Y1 : '4', Y2 : '5',Y3 : '10'}
```

I’ve tired to create the object by using **.reduce** but think there are more effiecent way to create the object.

```
let a = objs.reduce((total, obj) => obj['Y1'] + total, 0)
let b = objs.reduce((total, obj) => obj['Y2'] + total, 0)
let c = objs.reduce((total, obj) => obj['Y3'] + total, 0)

//then create new object and merge with exiting object
```

How can I achieve the object in more effiecent way?

Answer (score 1):

We can merge 3 `reduce` into only 1 `reduce` as below:

```js
let objs = [
    {Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1'},
    {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3'},
    {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6'}
    ]
    
let result1 = objs.reduce((a,c) =>{
  a.Y1 += +c.Y1
  a.Y2 += +c.Y2
  a.Y3 += +c.Y3
  return a
},{'Name':'Total','Y1':0,'Y2':0,'Y3':0})
console.log(result1)

let result2 = objs.reduce((a,{Y1,Y2,Y3}) =>{
  a.Y1 += +Y1
  a.Y2 += +Y2
  a.Y3 += +Y3
  return a
},{'Name':'Total','Y1':0,'Y2':0,'Y3':0})
console.log(result2)
```

---

Update:with dynamic keys

```js
let objs = [
    {Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1'},
    {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3'},
    {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6'}
    ]
    
let result = objs.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let keys = Object.keys(c).slice(1)
  keys.forEach(k => {
   a[k] += +c[k] 
  })
  return a
},{'Name':'Total','Y1':0,'Y2':0,'Y3':0})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The dynamic keys wouldn't work with any additional keys, you'd still need to initialize the keys to 0. You can improve it by just checking if a key is undefined, and if so initializing it to 0. Then you can remove the hard-coded initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this;

```js
let y1 = 0;
let y2 = 0;
let y3 = 0; 
let objs = [
    {"Name" : 'A', "Y1" : '1', "Y2" : '1', "Y3" : '1'},
    {"Name" : 'B', "Y1" : '2', "Y2" : '3', "Y3" : '3'},
    {"Name" : 'C', "Y1" : '1', "Y2" : '1', "Y3" : '6'}
]

objs.forEach((e)=>{
    y1 = y1 + parseInt(e["Y1"]);
    y2 = y2 + parseInt(e["Y2"]);
    y3 = y2 + parseInt(e["Y3"]);
});

console.log(y1);
console.log(y2);
console.log(y3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on flyingfox's answer with dynamic key value pairs:

```js
let objs = [
    {Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1', Y4: 'foo', Y5: '1'},
    {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3', Y4: '2'},
    {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6', Y5: 'bar'}
    ]
    
let result = objs.reduce((a,c) =>{
  const copy = {...c};
  delete copy.Name;
  const keys = Object.keys(copy)
  for (const k of keys) {
   const num = parseInt(c[k]);
   if (isNaN(num)) continue;
   if (a[k] === undefined) a[k] = 0;
   a[k] += num; 
  }
  return a
},{'Name':'Total'})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let objs = [
    { Name: "A", Y1: "1", Y2: "1", Y3: "1" },
    { Name: "B", Y1: "2", Y2: "3", Y3: "3" },
    { Name: "C", Y1: "1", Y2: "1", Y3: "6" },
  ];
  let tempY1 = 0;
  let tempY2 = 0;
  let tempY3 = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    tempY1 += parseInt(objs[i].Y1);
    tempY2 += parseInt(objs[i].Y2);
    tempY3 += parseInt(objs[i].Y3);
  }
  let newObj = { name: "total", Y1: tempY1, Y2: tempY2, Y3: tempY3 };
  console.log(newObj);
```

In this solution, we simply take the sum of all the key values by for loop for which you needed to store it in the temp variable, and after the completion of for loop, you good the data which you want in your question.

In case of any confusion drop a comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash - spread the array of objects into `_.mergeWith()` with the logic of summing the numeric values of all keys but `Name`. If the key is `Name` return "Total":

```js
const objs = [{Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1'},   {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3'}, {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6'}]
    
const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...objs, (a = 0, b, key) => 
  key === 'Name' ? 'Total' : a + +b
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you the sums to be strings as well, wrap the sum expression with `String()`:

```js
const objs = [{Name : 'A', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '1'},   {Name : 'B', Y1 : '2', Y2 : '3',Y3 : '3'}, {Name : 'C', Y1 : '1', Y2 : '1',Y3 : '6'}]
    
const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...objs, (a = 0, b, key) => 
  key === 'Name' ? 'Total' : String(+a + +b)
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**Note**: I'm using [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert strings to number, so this expression `+a + +b` converts both parameters to numbers, and then adds them.